# NoMethodError - undefined method `path' for nil:NilClass Cocoapods version 1.0

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoapods

This line is my podfile is causing this problem:

```
pod 'JiveCommon', :path => 'Common/JiveCommon'
```

At my root there is a file names "Common' and inside a project name JiveCommon witch is a pod by itself.

I used to use it like so at a submodule, so I can change and edit files from the current project context, but after upgrading to Cocoapods v 1.0 I get this error:

````
### Error

```
NoMethodError - undefined method `path' for nil:NilClass
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.0.0/lib/xcodeproj/project/object/native_target.rb:442:in `block in add_file_references'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.0.0/lib/xcodeproj/project/object/native_target.rb:441:in `map'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.0.0/lib/xcodeproj/project/object/native_target.rb:441:in `add_file_references'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/target_installer/pod_target_installer.rb:99:in `block in add_files_to_build_phases'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/target_installer/pod_target_installer.rb:75:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/target_installer/pod_target_installer.rb:75:in `add_files_to_build_phases'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/target_installer/pod_target_installer.rb:21:in `block in install!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.0/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:144:in `message'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/target_installer/pod_target_installer.rb:17:in `install!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:621:in `block (2 levels) in install_libraries'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:619:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:619:in `block in install_libraries'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.0/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:144:in `message'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:618:in `install_libraries'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:170:in `block in generate_pods_project'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.0/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:63:in `section'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:167:in `generate_pods_project'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:119:in `install!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.0/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:37:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/claide-1.0.0/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.0/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:50:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.0/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
```
````

I looked at the documentary if there is a diffrent best practice to use the 'Path' syntax, but didn't find anything..

The same issue comes up on Githb issues : https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/4814

But no solution resolved it.

Any one else experiencing the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've managed to solve this, if anyone else will facing the same issue, In the submodule pod spec, I've needed to change:

Changing the source_files does not help. I have a private podspec with previously containing

```
s.source_files = 'Common/**/*

To

s.source_files = 'Common/**/*.{m,h,mm,hpp,cpp,c}'
```